# Pandas DataFrame: Assign values from a column to a subset of original dataframe without copying

Tags: python, pandas

I want to assign the values of a column in a DataFrame to a subset of another column in the same original DataFrame. Consider the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=[0,1,1,2,1,3,4,5], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df['str'] = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
df.loc[1, 'B'] = df.loc[1, 'A']
```

For all values where the index is `1`, I want to assign the value of column `'A'` to column `'B'`. This operation is to be applied to the original DataFrame and not a copy.

The above example fails with the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-29c8017817b2> in <module>()
      2 df['str'] = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
      3 display(df)
----> 4 df.loc[1, 'B'] = df.loc[1, 'A']
      5 display(df)

~/anaconda/envs/snakes36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    177             key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    178         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 179         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    180 
    181     def _has_valid_type(self, k, axis):

~/anaconda/envs/snakes36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
    577 
    578                     if len(labels) != len(value):
--> 579                         raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
    580                                          'when setting with an iterable')
    581 

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

The problem seems to be column `str` which is of different type than the other `float64` columns. If I remove column `str`, the code above works perfectly. Which I do not understand as I assumed my `.loc` operations only select columns `A` and `B`.

The problem is: My DataFrame consists of ~50 columns with different types.

Is there a better approach to solve this?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 :** 
Use a conditional to match the index i.e

```
df.loc[df.index==1,'B'] =df.loc[1,'A']
```

**Option 2 :** 
or with `np.where` i.e

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['B'].index==1,df['A'],df['B'])
```

**Option 3 :** 
or with `df.where`

```
df['B']  = df['B'].where(~(df['B'].index==1),df['A'])
```

Output:

```
          A         B         C         D str
0 -0.549047 -0.608938 -0.355242  1.362221   a
1  0.298822  0.298822  1.591475  0.146636   a
1 -0.292439 -0.292439  0.425860  0.117091   a
2 -1.715484 -0.343491 -1.448902  1.394756   a
1  0.657651  0.657651 -0.002407  1.317446   a
3 -0.698070 -0.740400 -1.348418 -0.800586   a
4 -1.043036 -0.161858  1.110410  0.275207   a
5  0.050947 -1.424375  0.260261 -1.058468   a
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.index==1,'B'] = df.loc[1,'A']` would do too.

Comment: Thanks! As I need to perform similar operations on many large DataFrames, are all options similarly efficient?

Comment: Followup question: I noticed I also want to perform this operation on multiple columns at once. Example: `df.loc[df.index==1, ['A', 'B']] = df.loc[1, ['C', 'D']]` to assign `C` and `D` to `A` and `B`. This gives me `NaN` on `A` and `B` for all matching rows.

Comment: Looking around, I found `df.loc[df.index==1, ['A', 'B']] = df.loc[1, ['C', 'D']].values` to do the trick. Any better idea (performance-wise)?